# How to update the visual aspects of a NSTableCellView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I have a custom `NSTableCellView` with 2 `NSTextField`s, 1 `NSProgressIndicator` and 2 Buttons. 
I want to hide 1 button and the `Progress Indicator` when I reload the Table. The problem is if my `NSTableView` is hidden, when I reload it, the visual gets update, otherwise the `NSTableCellView` stays the same (the progress bar and label continues visible).

Here's an example:
[image]

The first row is updated (I reloaded the Data of the table when it was hidden) but the second is not (I reloaded the Data of the table when it was active and visible). 

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Why do you not want to use reloadData? I think you need to use that or reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes: to get the table to update its views -- you need to change the data in the data source first of course, but that won't update the table without one of those methods (unless you're using bindings).